# I'm not getting exception but when using a break point i see exception on the stream how can i solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";

                //On worker thread
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;

                //Back on calling thread
                var responseStream = GetCompressedStream(response);
                if (responseStream != null)
                    return Image.FromStream(responseStream);
            }
            catch(Exception eee)
            {
                string myerropr = eee.ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

And

```
private static Stream GetCompressedStream(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                return new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                return new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        }
        catch(EndOfStreamException ee)
        {
            string myer = ee.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

On the var stream when i use a breakpoint i see at Length:

> Length = 'stream.Length' threw an exception of type
>   'System.NotSupportedException'

Same exception on Position.

Then in the end both methods return null.

I couldn't catch the exceptions only when using break point i see them.

Comment: You'll find that these are internal exceptions that you don't need to worry about a runtime - this is why they aren't being thrown at all.  Subclasses of `Stream` offer a variety of different functionalities and not all of them support all properties and methods of the `Stream` base class. My advice is not to worry about them at all, and consider only the errors that are getting thrown to your exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article regarding the [NotSupportedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In your case, the exceptions are only happening internally (you can only see them whilst debugging), so you don't really need to worry about them.